# Corner radius of Macbooks?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm working on a sticker which I'll attach to a 15 inch MacBook Pro. I know that the size is:

```
Height: 0.71 inch (1.8 cm)
Width: 14.13 inches (35.89 cm)
Depth: 9.73 inches (24.71 cm)
```

but what about the corner radius? And is it the same as the other MacBooks? I'm using a 13 inch MacBook Air and don't have access to a 15 inch MacBook Pro.

Thanks!

**tl;dr**

What's the corner radius of a 15 inch MacBook Pro?

Comment: You say you're using both a 15in MBP and a 13in MBA. Which is it?

Comment: I'm doing a sticker FOR a 15in MBP ON a 13in MBA.

Answer (score -1):

It is 11 mm to 12 mm. Try measuring mine.